# No solution to "x^-d = e^100" (negative exponents)?

Tags: sympy

I am trying to automatically solve $x**-d - sympy.exp(100)$ with sympy.

```
import sympy
from sympy import solve, Symbol
x = Symbol('x')
d = Symbol('d', integer=True)

print(solve(x**-d - sympy.exp(100), x))
```

returns no solutions [], but the solution should be $x=e^{-100/d}$ (see e.g., [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%28x**-d+-+exp%28100%29+%3D+0%2C+x%29))

What did I do wrong? Same result when removing integer=True.

However,

```
print(solve(x**-d - sympy.exp(100), x))
```

returns `[exp(100/d)]`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution appears when `solve(check=False)` is given.

see Solving Equations Involving Radicals of
http://www.cfm.brown.edu/people/dobrush/am33/SymPy/solvers.html